# How to manage a non-node module as dependency for Node Project thorugh NPM?

Tags: npm, bower, dependency-management

I was using bower in my project for dependency management. But now I wanted to move to node and npm. But the problem is few of my dependencies are not node modules like [Smooth-Div-Scroll](https://github.com/tkahn/Smooth-Div-Scroll)[1](https://github.com/tkahn/Smooth-Div-Scroll) and  [swiftype-search-jquery](https://github.com/swiftype/swiftype-search-jquery)[2](https://github.com/swiftype/swiftype-search-jquery)

How to manage all those dependencies in my node project. When I tried doing

```
"swiftype-search-jquery": "git@github.com:swiftype/swiftype-search-jquery.git",
"smooth-div-scroll": "git@github.com:tkahn/Smooth-Div-Scroll.git",
```

it is not able to download dependency and throw error

```
npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON npm ERR! package.json Non-registry package missing package.json: swiftype-search-jquery@git+ssh://git@github.com/swiftype/swiftype-search-jquery.git. npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.
```

These dependencies don't have package.json in their folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, It is not possible with NPM but at the same time, it is possible with Yarn without making any change. Instead of "npm install" we have to use "yarn install" .

Add dependencies with git url which is not present with NPM .

Comment: what if the non-node package is designed with npm in mind and has a package.json?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible.
Here is a guide to migrate from bower to npm, it's pretty easy.

https://codecraft.tv/courses/angularjs-migration/step-2-typescript-and-webpack/converting-bower-to-npm/